# List index out of range when trying to generate gif from plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a GIF for an image I created. However, I am encountering this error message

```
MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable; trying to use <class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter'> instead.
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in finish(self)
    573 
    574     def finish(self):
--> 575         self._frames[0].save(
    576             self._outfile, save_all=True, append_images=self._frames[1:],
    577             duration=int(1000 / self.fps), loop=0)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code

```
from matplotlib import animation, rc

#Set the plot up,
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
plt.title('Sale Price vs Living Area')
plt.xlabel('Living Area in square feet (normalised)')
plt.ylabel('Sale Price ($)')
plt.scatter(x[:,1], y, color='red')
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
annotation = ax.text(-1, 700000, '')
annotation.set_animated(True)
plt.close()
#Generate the animation data,
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    annotation.set_text('')
    return line, annotation
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(-5, 20, 1000)
    y = past_thetas[i][1]*x + past_thetas[i][0]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    annotation.set_text('Cost = %.2f e10' % (past_costs[i]/10000000000))
    return line, annotation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=300, interval=0, blit=True)
anim.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps = 30)
```

This is a sample of what I have in past_thetas

```
[array([0.61279458, 0.07571964]),
 array([5402.42825457, 2578.99911609]),
 array([10750.22555995,  5132.1344718 ]),
 array([16044.54489229,  7659.73965526]),
 array([21285.9210313 , 10162.06995636]),
 array([26474.88340892, 12639.37811224]),
 array([31611.95616276, 15091.91433277]),
 array([36697.65818907, 17519.92632585]),
 array([41732.50319511, 19923.65932241]),
 array([46716.99975109, 22303.35610116]),
 array([51651.65134151, 24659.25701318]),
 array([56536.95641603, 26991.60000612]),
 array([61373.4084398 , 29300.62064827]),
 array([66161.49594334, 31586.55215234]),
 array([70901.70257184, 33849.62539904]),
 array([75594.50713405, 36090.06896035]),
 array([80240.38365065, 38308.10912268]),
 array([84839.80140207, 40503.96990963]),
 array([89393.22497599, 42677.87310471]),
 array([93901.11431416, 44830.03827366]),
 array([98363.92475895, 46960.6827867 ]),
 array([102782.10709929,  49070.02184043]),
 array([107156.10761624,  51158.26847958]),
 array([111486.36812801,  53225.63361853]),
 array([115773.32603466,  55272.32606263]),
 array([120017.41436225,  57298.55252927]),
 array([124219.06180656,  59304.51766874]),
 array([128378.69277642,  61290.42408495]),
 array([132496.72743659,  63256.47235584]),
 array([136573.58175016,  65202.86105368]),
 array([140609.66752059,  67129.78676511]),
 array([144605.39243332,  69037.44411098]),
 array([148561.16009692,  70926.02576604]),
 array([152477.37008388,  72795.72247837]),
 array([156354.41797098,  74646.72308865]),
 array([160192.6953792 ,  76479.21454926]),
 array([163992.59001334,  78293.38194312]),
 array([167754.48570114,  80089.40850244]),
 array([171478.76243206,  81867.47562715]),
 array([175165.79639568,  83627.76290331]),
 array([178815.96001965,  85370.44812116]),
 array([182429.62200739,  87095.70729314])]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `imagemagick` installed?

Comment: @Błotosmętek I initially didn't but now I do, same error still